# laravel filter ajax and pagination

Tags: ajax, laravel, filter, pagination

I want to filter products in my category with price desc or asc or newest(id desc). But my ajax filter only action in first page

This is my view and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sort(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{!!URL::to('cate/update') !!}',
            data: {'sort': value, 'id': {{ $id }} },
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('body').html(data)
                    }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
if ($request->sort == 1) {
    $data['items'] = Product::where('prod_cate', $request->id)->orderby('promotion_price', 'asc')->paginate(3);
} else if ($request->sort == 2) {
    $data['items'] = Product::where('prod_cate', $request->id)->orderby('promotion_price', 'desc')->paginate(3);
}else{
        $data['items'] = Product::where('prod_cate', $request->id)->orderby('prod_id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
}

return view('frontend.product_type', $data);
```

Comment: You will have to send a seperate ajax request for each of your pagination pages

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: by repeating the ajax, but each time increment `?page=#`, the `#` being for example `+ i++`, until the request no longer returns results

Comment: i tried but still dont know how to do that

Comment: How many products do you have in the database? if you are unable to make a frontend paginator i would suggest removing the paginator alltogether if there are not a lot of results.

Comment: i have many products . But  let's you show me the way of you.
Or can you teamviewer for me. Many thanks

Comment: do you want to paginate until all products are returned in batches of 3? or do you indend to only show 3 at the time on the frontend, but have it sorted?

Comment: 3 is an example number is here. I want to paginate until all products are returned in batches